# Netplan DNS nameserver setting not being applied

Tags: dns, systemd, netplan, systemd-networkd

I'm renting a VPS from [Linode](https://www.linode.com) with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) installed on it.
But the default DNS server from Linode doesn't resolve a domain name which I really need it to resolve. Therefore, I tried to edit my netplan configuration to change the DNS server to Google's one, since the VPS is obviously headless. I edited the file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml to contain the following:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Ubuntu 20.04 was using networkd as the netplan backend by default. I linted the YAML and it is correctly formatted. DHCP is on by default (as by setting dhcp4: yes) and turning it off (by setting dhcp4: no) does not correct the problem. eth0 is the name of my network connection as per `ip a`. However, whenever I run `sudo netplan apply` after saving the netplan configuration file the active nameserver does not seem to change as per `sudo systemd-resolve --status`. Even forcing networkd to restart by running `sudo ip link set eth0 down` and `sudo ip link set eth0 up` or restarting systemd-resolved by running `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved` does nothing.

Why is it so difficult to change the DNS server on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS? Am I missing something here?

Thank you so much in advance for your help,
Joshua

**EDIT:**
Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=virtio-pci latency=0
       resources: irq:20 ioport:c080(size=64) memory:febd3000-febd3fff memory:fe
008000-fe00bfff memory:feb80000-febbffff
     *-virtio2
          description: Ethernet interface
          physical id: 0
          bus info: virtio@2
          logical name: eth0
          serial: f2:3c:93:91:e5:ed
          capabilities: ethernet physical
          configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net
driverversion=1.0.0 ip=170.187.185.46 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Output of `sudo ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Feb 24 06:53 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Output of `sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search members.linode.com
```

Output of `sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

Output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to https://netplan.io/reference/ and review the section on **DHCP Overrides**.

/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot` # if required

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't work. I don't get any errors or anything. The active DNS server in systemd-resolve --status is just not changed. Could this be enforced on a network level somehow?

Comment: @JoshuaSchroijen Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Let me know when you've got it for me.

Comment: I've added the information. Thanks for your help. Although I'm starting to believe that somehow Linode is blocking changing nameservers (through a firwall or something) and systemd is picking up on that and assigning a legal nameserver. I have no idea how to test this, though.

Comment: @JoshuaSchroijen Everything looks proper. Contact the Linode support folks and see if they have an answer. Report back.

Comment: I contacted Linode support but I think they just say to wait until their DNS server picks up the domain I can't resolve and that the DNS server can't really be changed.

Comment: @JoshuaSchroijen That sounds a little indeterminate, or they're just being lazy. Push back. Ask them how their DNS server will pick up the domain that you want, 'cause all you're getting now is DNS failures? And their DNS servers **CAN'T** be changed, or they just don't **WANT** you to use other servers? What is the site/domain that you're trying to reach?

Comment: @JoshuaSchroijen You could try editing /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Thanks for your continued input. Unfortunately, it seems to be a deeper issue than a DNS  one. Editing /etc/hosts did allow me to nslookup the domain but I think the webserver I'm connecting to is blocking the IP range my Linode is in (pinging it doesn't work).
So its deeper than DNS and I think that at this point I'm trying to circumvent deliberate restrictions. Obviously, I really don't intend to do that so I accept that I can't make a connection.

Comment: @JoshuaSchroijen OK, if you're getting blocked, bring up a VPN, and see if you can get your desired DNS and domain sites. Free VPN's aren't the best choice for a VPN, but for testing purposes...

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that by default systemd will not search for hostnames on the local network.  To fix this you need to edit your netplan config file to include a search field in your name servers.

So for example to search on a local domain named tacos.local you need to make it look like this if your name servers were 192.168.1.1 and .2. This however also gives you back a non authoritative answer for some reason as well.

```
nameservers: 
       search: [tacos.local]
       addresses: [192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command shows that `/etc/resolve.conf` points to the stub resolver, which is a local caching nameserver.

```
sudo ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Feb 24 06:53 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

If you want to you use the uplink nameserver, simply change what file the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` points to: `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.

```
sudo rm /etc/resolve.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

This is outlined in the man page for `systemd-resolved`: [systemd-resolved manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html)

```
/ETC/RESOLV.CONF         top

       Four modes of handling /etc/resolv.conf (see resolv.conf(5)) are
       supported:

       •   systemd-resolved maintains the
           /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf file for compatibility
           with traditional Linux programs. This file lists the
           127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as the only DNS server. It
           also contains a list of search domains that are in use by
           systemd-resolved. The list of search domains is always kept
           up-to-date. Note that /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
           should not be used directly by applications, but only through
           a symlink from /etc/resolv.conf. This file may be symlinked
           from /etc/resolv.conf in order to connect all local clients
           that bypass local DNS APIs to systemd-resolved with correct
           search domains settings. This mode of operation is
           recommended.

       •   A static file /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf is provided that
           lists the 127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as only DNS server.
           This file may be symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf in order to
           connect all local clients that bypass local DNS APIs to
           systemd-resolved. This file does not contain any search
           domains.

       •   systemd-resolved maintains the
           /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf file for compatibility with
           traditional Linux programs. This file may be symlinked from
           /etc/resolv.conf and is always kept up-to-date, containing
           information about all known DNS servers. Note the file
           format's limitations: it does not know a concept of
           per-interface DNS servers and hence only contains system-wide
           DNS server definitions. Note that
           /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf should not be used directly
           by applications, but only through a symlink from
           /etc/resolv.conf. If this mode of operation is used local
           clients that bypass any local DNS API will also bypass
           systemd-resolved and will talk directly to the known DNS
           servers.

       •   Alternatively, /etc/resolv.conf may be managed by other
           packages, in which case systemd-resolved will read it for DNS
           configuration data. In this mode of operation
           systemd-resolved is consumer rather than provider of this
           configuration file.

       Note that the selected mode of operation for this file is
       detected fully automatically, depending on whether
       /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
       or lists 127.0.0.53 as DNS server.
```